# Create dynamic number of click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a function that will automatically scroll to the active option in a bootstrap multiselect dropdown list. However, I have been unable to modify my code to work with a variable number of dropdowns at the same time. My problem lies in creating multiple functions, or having a single function be capable of do this.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $dropdowns = $('fieldset').find("button.multiselect"); //Find all the dropdowns
                    console.log($dropdowns); //Show the ones that have been found
                    $.each($dropdowns, function (i) { //Just get the index of each
                        console.log(i); //Show index
                        myFunction(i); //Create n different .click functions (each with their own globals)
                    });

                    function myFunction(index) {
                        var not_found = true;
                        var jump_to = 0;
                        var temp = -1;
                        //Recursively find scrolling value in pixels, then move. 
                        //This works for a single dropdown.
                        $('button.multiselect:eq(index)').click(function () {  
                            if (not_found == true) {
                                $('.multiselect:eq(index)').dropdown('toggle');
                                temp = $('ul.multiselect-container:eq(index) li.active').position().top;
                                $('.multiselect:eq(index)').dropdown('toggle');
                                if (temp > jump_to) {
                                    jump_to = temp;
                                    not_found = false;
                                }
                                else if (temp <= jump_to) {
                                    $("button.multiselect:eq(index)").click();
                                }
                            }
                            console.log($('ul.multiselect-container:eq(index) li.active').text());
                            $('ul.multiselect-container:eq(index)').animate({scrollTop: jump_to}, 750); //Scroll to active element
                        })
                    }
                });
```

I'm not sure if I should be using some trickery with [addEventListener()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you need to do is take `index` out of your string and pass the variable instead:

```
$('button.multiselect:eq('+index+')') 
...
$('.multiselect:eq('+index+')').dropdown('toggle');
...
```

for all instances of `index`

Comment: Haha, I feel like a fool. That fixed it. Cheers.